# Why does it keep saying the capacity of my dynamic array is 2 even though I keep changing it so it is not 2?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

I want to print out the capacity of my dynamic arrays, but no matter how I change it, it keeps saying that the capacity of both the arrays are 2.

The code (tmp.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  int *ptr1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
  int capacity_ptr1 = sizeof(ptr1)/sizeof(int);
  printf("capacity of ptr1 is: %d\n", capacity_ptr1 );

  int *ptr2 = (int *)realloc(ptr1, sizeof(int) * 5);
  printf("capacity of ptr2 is: %ld\n", sizeof(ptr2)/sizeof(int) );



  return 0;
}
```

What I execute in terminal

```
gcc -std=c99 tmp.c -o tmp
./tmp
```

The output in terminal

```
capacity of ptr1 is: 2
capacity of ptr2 is: 2
```

I get this output no matter what capacity parameter I enter for malloc() and realloc()

Comment: `sizeof(ptr2)` doesn't give you the capacity of the allocated memory. All it gives you is the size of an `int` pointer, which stays the same.

Comment: `sizeof` a pointer is the size of the actual pointer, not what it might be pointing to. When you do dynamic allocation in C you have to keep track of the "size" yourself.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: `sizeof array / sizeof *array` only apply to *Arrays*, and only within the *scope* in which they were declared. `int *ptr1` declares a pointer, so `sizeof ptr1` is `sizeof (a_pointer)` (generally 8-bytes on x86_64) and `sizeof (int)` is `4`. No matter how many `int` you allocate for `sizeof ptr1 / sizeof (int)` will ways be `2` on x86_64 .

Comment: Use search engine. It is one if the most frequent duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You take the size of a pointer (not an array), which is usually 64 bits then divide it by the size of an int, which is usually 32 bits. This is why you get 2 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. [Arrays are not pointers, and vice-versa](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr)
2. You are not checking the size of allocated memory, anyways.

To elaborate, the problem here is, `sizeof(ptr1)` does not yield the size of the valid memory pointed to by the pointer, it returns the size of the pointer itself. Size of a pointer (or any type, for that matter), is constant.

For the pointers returned by allocator functions, there's so straight way to get the size of the requested (and allocated) memory size from the pointer itself, you need to keep track of the size yourself.

That said: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: One of the most common duplicates